# Symfony CSRF check failing

Tags: symfony, csrf

Getting:

```
"The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form."
```

Controller:

```
$message = new Message();
$form = $this->createForm(new MessageType($locales), $message);
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        ...
        // never reached
    }
}
```

Inspecting the raw POST data, it does include a `_token` field:

```
message[title]: Test
message[subtitle]:
message[_token]:0LpwU3llG-FhyEc0o12b7rU0Pg2zSAb7xpUwAF1Xw3g
```

So it's not the issue lots are having missing `{{ form_rest(form) }}`

Answer (score 0):

Have you read this from the docs (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/csrf_in_login_form.html)?

> First, configure the Security component so it can use CSRF protection. The Security component needs a CSRF token provider. You can set this to use the default provider available in the Security component

```
# app/config/security.yml 
security: 
  # ... 
  firewalls: 
    secured_area: 
      # ... 
      form_login: 
        # ... 
        csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
```

I think maybe you need to specify which token manager to use for the _token